# I want to show data on chart bar when I search by date wise using Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have chart bar and I am trying to show data by date wise when I filter by date but unfortunately data does not show on chart bar. I want that when I select a start date and end date record should be shown on chart bar by date wise.

[image]

[image]

**Controller**

```
public function status(Request $request)
    {
        $date = explode(' - ', $request->date);

          $manager_hourlog = Hourlog::with('project', "user")->whereBetween('date', $date)
          ->get()
          ->groupBy('project.name');

        $projects = [];
        $totals = [];
        foreach ($manager_hourlog as $key => $val) {
            $projects[] = $key;
        }
        foreach ($manager_hourlog as $key2 => $val) {

            $minutes = $val->sum('hour_work');

            $totals[] = round($minutes / 60, 1);
        }
        $users = User::where("status", 1)->get();
        
        $data = [
            // manager report
            'manager_projects' => $projects,
            'totals' => $totals,
            "manager_hourlog" => $manager_hourlog,

        ];
           return $data;
        return  response()->json($data, 200);
    }
```

**html view**

```
      <form  action="{{route('dashboard')}}" method="post"  >
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group theme-input-group select-max-h-200">
        <div class="input-group-prepend width-160px">
          <div class="input-group-text">Date
          </div>
        </div>
        <input parsley-trigger="change" required type="text"  id="date"  class="form-control" name="date"  autocomplete="off">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="md md-event-note">
            </i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- input-group -->
    </div> 
  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-1">
  <div class="text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-light-theme waves-effect waves-light" id="search" name="search" type="submit">
      <i class="fa fa-search pr-1">
      </i> Search
    </button>
  </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#search').on('click', function () {
var date = $("#date").val();
$.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: '{{Route("dashboard.status")}}',
        data: {
                date: date
             },
       dataType: "JSon",
       success: function(response){
            // Employee  report script
          var colors = ["#1abc9c", "#2ecc71", "#3498db", "#9b59b6", "#34495e", "#16a085", "#27ae60", "#2980b9", "#8e44ad", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#e67e22", "#e74c3c", "#ecf0f1", "#95a5a6", "#f39c12", "#d35400", "#c0392b", "#bdc3c7", "#7f8c8d"];
              @if ($auth->user_type != 1) 
              // manager  report script
              var managerchartbar = {
              labels: {!! json_encode($manager_projects) !!},
                datasets: [
              @foreach($users  as  $user)
                  {
                    label: {!! json_encode($user->name) !!},
                    backgroundColor: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
                    data: [
                      @foreach($manager_hourlog as $hourlog) 
                        {{$hourlog->where("user_id", $user->id)->sum("hour_work") / 60}},
                      @endforeach
                    ]
                  },
              @endforeach
                ]
              };
                var ctx = document.getElementById('manager').getContext('2d');
                window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                  type: 'bar',
                  data: managerchartbar,
                  options: {
                    title: {
                      display: true,
                      text: 'Project Report chart'
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                      mode: 'index',
                      intersect: false
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                      xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                      }],
                      yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                      }]
                    }
                  }
                });

              @endif
              console.log(response);
          },
      error: function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }});
        });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Hi Zubair. Please try to refrain from adding "please help me" (and other forms of begging) to all of your posts. Readers here are volunteers, and do not want to be coerced into helping. Thanks!